# Create react app throwing errors 'unable to resolve dependency tree' and 'fix upstream dependency conflict'

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I've been trying use create react app but when I go to create it in the terminal i get this error.

```sh
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: test3@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/chrisheibel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR!`
```

I've tried using `--legacy-peer-deps` and `--force` with no luck. It will create the app but npm start does not work. Once i've created it i've tried to install/update npm and node again with no luck. I've also uninstalled node and npm globally on my computer and reinstalled with no luck, as well as turning react and react-dom in the created app to version 17 instead of 18 but had no luck there.

I'm at a bit of a loss on this one as create react app has always worked on my computer before. But maybe you guys might know if i'm missing something here and that's why I can't run npm start/ am getting all these errors.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is telling you what the issue is. The important parts are:

```sh
Found: react@18.0.0
```

and

```sh
peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
```

So `@testing-library/react@12.1.5` is only compatible with react <18 and you have added react 18, which breaks this rule. Upgrade `@testing-library/react` to a compatible version or downgrade react to < 18.

the latest version of [`@testing-library/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react) is 13. so you should likely have something like

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0"
```

in your package.json

Answer (score -1):

I'd check your version of create-react-app

```
create-react-app --version
```

Mine says 5.0.0.

The [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) says to uninstall create-react-app and run it using npx.  Running with npx will install the latest version:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

When I run create-react-app today I get a react v18 app.  In some cases I've had to downgrade it to v17.  I've done this as follows:

```
npm uninstall react react-dom
npm install react@!7 react-dom@17
```

Comment: Well yes, downgrading react will fix the issue, but you can't just not upgrade because of a dependency issue.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to downgrade to v17 from v18.  It is necessary to do this in order to use many packages right now.

Comment: No, the questions says they've tried downgrading with no luck. *as well as turning react and react-dom in the created app to version 17 instead of 18 **but had no luck there**.* The conflicting library has a compatible upgrade, so the solution is to upgrade that.